# Algorithm for planning a meal

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, dynamic-programming, linear-programming

I am having trouble coming up with an algorithm to generate a meal plan. The problem involves coming up with **different amounts of food items** given the nutrition requirements(carbohydrates, fats, proteins, etc). The food items need to be selected from a small number of items( < 7). For example lets say you have food items A,B,C. Food item A has a_p grams of protein for 1 gram of A, item B as b_p grams of protein for 1 gram of B and so on. Lets say the total number of carbs required is Crb, total amount of protein required is Prt and fat required is Ft. For this problem the equations will look like

`A_g*a_p + B_g*b_p + C_g*c_p = Prt
 A_g*a_c + B_g*b_c + C_g*c_c = Crb
 A_g*a_f + B_g*b_f + C_g*c_f = Ft`

where A_g,B_g and C_g are grams of each food item and a_p...b_c...c_f denote the grams of protein, carbs and fats in 1 gram of each of the respective foods. The problem here is that most of the times it will not be possible to satisfy the given requirements and only the best solution is required which is closest to the given requirements. The overall goal is to reduce the difference between the actual nutrient requirements and the one calculated by the algorithm. I have looked into linear programming but most of the the problems I have seen involve minimizing/maximizing a given function with a set of constraints. I will greatly appreciate any kind help in solving this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "closest to the given requirements"? Any computable method must have a well defined function to be minimized or maximized. I can suggest some functions, but you have to understand your domain before coming out with an algorithm

Comment: For small number of items, you can just try every combination, which time complexity is O(2^n), with n is number of items.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity @JuanLopes. What I meant was that the algorithm doesn't necessarily have to match the exact nutrient requirement. The goal is to reduce the error between the actual requirements and the one produced by the algorithm.That is minimize the function (Prt - Prt_a)^2 + (Crb - Crb_a)^2 + (Ft - Ft_a) ^2 where Prt_a, Crb_a and Ft_a are the amounts of nutrients calculated by the algorithm.

Comment: @PhamTrung That will mean the problem is binary. I have to come up with discrete amounts of each food given the nutrition content and nutrient requirements.

Comment: I see, how about the limit for Crb, Prt and Ft? if it is small, you can use dynamic programming with this state dp[index][Crb][Prt][Ft]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are allowed to have fractional grams of food items, you can solve this problem analytically, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29 for details.

You have the additional implicit constraint that none of the foods can be present in negative amount.  So if foods appear in a negative amount, you will need to try different subsets of the foods to find the possible answers and then pick the best one.

If you cannot have fractional amounts of some food items, then this problem becomes substantially more difficult.

Comment: Thanks @btilly, the food amount can indeed be fractional. I also found a wiki article about non negative least squares: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares.